# How to disable WHOIS "Statutory Masking Enabled"?

Tags: domain-registrar, whois

I searched here for "Statutory Masking Enabled", and it's not found. My domain is registered to web.com. Anybody running a WHOIS search on my domain finds practically no information because everything except the nameservers is hidden by "Statutory Masking Enabled". This means the WHOIS record gives no information about the domain's registrant (me) or the administrative or technical contacts. There is no way for anyone to contact me except through the owners of the nameservers. I never asked for this info to be hidden. Anybody know the rule (ICANN?) that allows registrars to do this and how can it be disabled?

PS: I found some [news from 2018 about this](https://editations.org/statutory-masking-enabled-meaning), which says it's being done to "throttle transfers out".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Domain Privacy](https://www.web.com/domains/domain-privacy) is a feature offered by web.com and turned on by default for certain purchases.

To turn it off, follow the instructions under the [How Do I Manage Perfect Privacy/Private Registration](https://customerservice.web.com/prweb/PRAuth/app/WebKM_/JfLhd8LVz0a16-h3GqsHOCqqFky5N_vd*/!autoThread1?pzuiactionzzz=CXtycX02NWZmNGM5ZWZiM2NjM2U0YTBmM2ViNzc5MmVkYjM1MDljZDA5MzY5ZDhlM2U5NzkwMjA2YmVhNDlmYjJmYTNhOWFlMWJhMDI3YmY4ZTdhZTg3NDUxM2M0ZWMwNWZkYTBmNzZhMmViNWU1M2E3MDRjNjM4ODQxZWU5MjE1ODViMDNmNDZhMWUyNDg2MDIzYTQ1ODVkOTI2NzZiMDY5MTc0ZjVmMGY2ZmNiMTdkOGNjMzIwZDdhZGNkY2Q1ZWMzNWY%3D*#:%7E:text=Back%20to%20Top%20%E2%87%A7-,How%20Do%20I%20Manage%20Perfect%20Privacy/Private%20Registration%3F,-Private%20Domain%20Registration) section in the linked support article.

Comment: Thanks, but it's different - with their Domain Privacy you get as your WHOIS domain registrant Perfect Privacy LLC with their street address and phone number. My WHOIS is all "Statutory masking".